# Deploy to GKE when there is new image in Cloud Repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

I have a very interesting task.
I'm using 5 different triggers to build 5 images on every push in gitbranch.
After they are built I push them to 5 different GCP Container registries.

I want to automate the GKE deployment, so when I have new image in the registry to deploy them to GKE automatically.
How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

I proposed you something very similar. Instead of use Container Registry, use [Artifact registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry). Create a Docker registry and use it as you use Container Registry.

Then, activate the audit logs on artifact registry
[image]

*You only need the write audit logs in this case*

Finally, create a Cloud Logging sink to PubSub on this filter:

```
protoPayload.serviceName="artifactregistry.googleapis.com"
protoPayload.methodName="Docker-PutManifest"
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.resource="projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<YOUR_LOCATION>/repositories/<REPOSITORY_NAME>"
```

Now, you only have to listen this event with Cloud Function or Cloud Run and do what you want, deploy a new revision for example.